# Powerpivot DAX KPI- relative targets

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a KPI that measures the number of new widgets month to date

```
NewWidget:=
  TOTALMTD(
      Calculate(
           count([Time]),[NewWidget]="yes")
   ,[Logdate])
```

There are many personnel who can open new widgets though. I would like to set a relative target for each person of 10% of the ALL new widgets opened MTD. How can I change the KPI so that it measures the number of new widgets per user MTD, divided by the GRAND TOTAL of new widgets MTD?

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do is use the `ALL` function to override the context used in the calculation.

So using your NewWidget formula already created.

The first step would be to write a calculate statement which ignores the context of the personnel.  The below would be an example where it would calculate the [NewWidget] calculation but would ignore the context of personnel.

```
TotalAllPersonal:= CALCULATE( [NewWidget], ALL('personnel_table_name_here'))
```

Then each personnel weight would be a quick division:

```
PersonnelWeight:= DIVIDE ( [NewWidget] , [TotalAllPersonal] )
```